# Replace value with np.where and create an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy

I have a list like that:

```
my_list = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']
```

I'm using `np.where` to replace "banana" with the integer "5":

```
my_list = np.where(my_list=='banana', 5, my_list)
```

but the output is

```
>> ['apple', 'orange', '5']
```

and I need

```
>> ['apple', 'orange', 5]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You are using numpy arrays.  One of the basic tenents of Numpy is "The elements in a NumPy array are all required to be of the same data type, and thus will be the same size in memory. The exception: one can have arrays of (Python, including NumPy) objects, thereby allowing for arrays of different sized elements." (From [Numpy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/numpy-user.pdf))

Comment: Okay, I didn't know and that solved my problem. I'm just going to convert everything to numbers (represented as str) and then convert the whole array to integers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can a map function be used instead..

```
my_list = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']
list(map(lambda x:5 if x=='banana' else x, my_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using python lists, stick with python. This is especially a good idea if you want mixed data types. `np.where` will not be especially efficient in looping through an array of python objects. Here is a numpy solution:

```
my_list = [5 if x == 'orange' else x for x in my_list]
```

As an aside, you can create a list of the indices where `my_list` contains `'orange'`, like the 1-arg form of `np.where`, using a similar comprehension:

```
indices = [i, for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if x == 'orange']
```